# How do I fix misquoted CSV files to allow parsing them with the csv module?

Tags: python, csv

I'd like the below code to avoid splitting within double quotes, but it does:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

contents = """
gene "Tagln2"; note "putative; transgelin 2 (MGD|MGI:1312985 GB|BC049861, evidence: BLASTN, 99%, match=1379)"; product "transgelin-2"; protein_id "NP_848713.1"; tag "RefSeq Select"; exon_number "4";
"""

for l in csv.reader(StringIO(contents), delimiter=";", quotechar='"', skipinitialspace=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL):
    print(l)
```

outputs:

```
['gene "Tagln2"', 'note "putative', 'transgelin 2 (MGD|MGI:1312985 GB|BC049861, evidence: BLASTN, 99%, match=1379)"', 'product "transgelin-2"', 'protein_id "NP_848713.1"', 'tag "RefSeq Select"', 'exon_number "4"', '']
```

You can see that it splits within the double quotes so that `note "putative; transgelin 2"` becomes `['note "putative', 'transgelin 2']`. How do I fix this?

Comment: field values containing your separator character are not protected in your data: if your field values contain a char with special semantics in the context of csv parsing - such as the separator char ';'  - then the _entire_ field value has to be wrapped/protected by the quotechar you pass to the reader. this is not the case in your data where the " char is just another ordinary data character....

Comment: ...ps...the downvote wasn't mine. @Timeless' answer looks good if you can't fix the file

Comment: @mrxra, agreed, fixing line-by-line might be an option (and, maybe, preferable to shlex). I've suggested a way to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems a good usecase for [`shlex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) :

```
import shlex
​
lexer = shlex.shlex(contents, posix=True)
lexer.whitespace_split = True
lexer.whitespace = ";"
​
out1 = [e.strip() for e in lexer if e.strip() != ""]
```

Or if you wanna preserve the quotes, you can use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) :

```
import re

out2 = [e.strip() for e in re.split(r'(?<=")\s*;\s*', contents) if e != ""]
```

Output :

```
print(out1)

['gene Tagln2',
 'note putative; transgelin 2 (MGD|MGI:1312985 GB|BC049861, evidence: BLASTN, 99%, match=1379)',
 'product transgelin-2',
 'protein_id NP_848713.1',
 'tag RefSeq Select',
 'exon_number 4']

print(out2)

['gene "Tagln2"',
 'note "putative; transgelin 2 (MGD|MGI:1312985 GB|BC049861, evidence: BLASTN, 99%, match=1379)"',
 'product "transgelin-2"',
 'protein_id "NP_848713.1"',
 'tag "RefSeq Select"',
 'exon_number "4"']
```

Comment: I'll test how much slower shlex is than my current solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Like mrxra pointed out in the comments of the question, `...; "putative; transgelin 2..."` by itself is good; `...; note "putative; transgelin 2..."` is not.

I'd re-title this question, "Working w/misquoted CSV", because that's the core issue: whatever generated the file prefixed the (correctly encoded) quoted data with fieldnames, which breaks the CSV encoding.

You can fix this with a fairly simple function that:

- has an iterator over the input text
- iterates each input line and fixes the problems
- yields the fixed line (for the csv reader to decode)

```py
import csv
from io import StringIO

from typing import Iterator

contents = """
gene "Tagln2"; note "putative; transgelin 2 (MGD|MGI:1312985 GB|BC049861, evidence: BLASTN, 99%, match=1379)"; product "transgelin-2"; protein_id "NP_848713.1"; tag "RefSeq Select"; exon_number "4";
gene "TaglnX"; note "putative; transgelin X (MGD|MGI:XXXXXXX GB|YYYYYYYY, evidence: BLASTN, 11%, match=0000)"; product "transgelin-X"; protein_id "QQQQQQQQQQQ"; tag "RefSeq Select"; exon_number "M";
""".strip()


def fix_misquotes() -> Iterator[str]:
    for line in StringIO(contents):
        line = line.replace('gene "', '"gene ')
        line = line.replace('; note "', '; "note ')
        line = line.replace('; product "', '; "product ')
        line = line.replace('; protein_id "', '; "protein_id ')
        line = line.replace('; tag "', '; "tag ')
        line = line.replace('; exon_number "', '; "exon_number ')

        yield line


reader = csv.reader(fix_misquotes(), delimiter=";", quotechar='"', skipinitialspace=True)
for row in reader:
    for field in row:
        print(field)
```

When I run that I get:

```
gene Tagln2
note putative; transgelin 2 (MGD|MGI:1312985 GB|BC049861, evidence: BLASTN, 99%, match=1379)
product transgelin-2
protein_id NP_848713.1
tag RefSeq Select
exon_number 4

gene TaglnX
note putative; transgelin X (MGD|MGI:XXXXXXX GB|YYYYYYYY, evidence: BLASTN, 11%, match=0000)
product transgelin-X
protein_id QQQQQQQQQQQ
tag RefSeq Select
exon_number M
```

A core concept of this approach is that csv.reader only needs *an iterator over lines of text*—the `open(...)` function returns such a thing, as does `StringIO(...)`.  So, the fix-it function should return such a thing.  It ends up *intercepting* a line and trying to fix just before csv.reader tries to decode it.

If the fieldnames themselves are problematic, remove the fieldname in the replace functions (keeping the double-quote):

```py
...
line = line.replace('gene "', '"')
line = line.replace('; note "', '; "')
...
```

to get:

```
Tagln2
putative; transgelin 2 (MGD|MGI:1312985 GB|BC049861, evidence: BLASTN, 99%, match=1379)
transgelin-2
NP_848713.1
RefSeq Select
4

TaglnX
putative; transgelin X (MGD|MGI:XXXXXXX GB|YYYYYYYY, evidence: BLASTN, 11%, match=0000)
transgelin-X
QQQQQQQQQQQ
RefSeq Select
M
```

To work with an actual file, and not a hard-coded example string:

```py
def fix_misquotes() -> Iterator[str]:
    with open("input.csv", newline="") as f_in:
        for line in f_in:
            ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll play around with your reply. One problem with my input is that each line can contain different fields. But it should be possible to generalize your cleaning function.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat, right, too many fields and shlex approach probably wins out. Good luck!